# Is it Possible to Read Specific Block of Text

Tags: c#, file-io

Is it possible to use `Streamreader` (or I guess something other than `Streamreader`) to read a specific block of text?  An example would be that I have chart like data in a text file that is separated by date and I want to read each day's data separately.  Example of the data is shown below.

[image]

- Blue - The date
- Red - The first chunk of data I want pull per day
- Green - The second chunk of data I want pull per day (only the numbers need to be read)

When I search for methods to do this I seem to only find reading entire text files or read individuals lines.  The second option may seem feasible but the problem there is that I don't have the same amount of entries every day so I would need to dynamically determine how many lines to read.  I am thinking the best approach would be to tell my `Streamreader` to read all the text between two words like "FAIL" and "Total".  But since I can't find anything online I'm not sure if it's possible and if it is, how to go about doing it.  Any help is appreciated.

Incase it matters I plan on taking the text from the file into Excel so I'll probably have to put the output into an array or something but that's a problem for later.

Comment: How is a generic library method supposed to determine this, if not by lines? You will need to write code to *parse* the lines and determine when to continue or stop reading.

Comment: @CodyGray are saying to look at every line and then determine what I want to keep based on that text of those lines?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to do it.

Comment: _"Learning how to break a problem into smaller manageable chunks, learning to program is.  That way, more than likely going to find the api method you need, you are.  Yeesssssss."_ - [Yoda](http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/index.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be as simple as writing down how YOU would do it yourself.
Something like this:

- Read lines until you see a date; remember the date.
- Read lines until line is Red Block header.
- Read lines until line is Green Block Header; while not found add line to Red Block Data.
- Read lines until EOF or until date encountered; while not found add line to Green Block Data.
- Repeat if EOF was not found.

How to do each step is a matter of preference. But by decomposing it, you make a seemingly complicated problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

This is called *Parsing* and you need to write your own parser.

By the look of it, it would be very easy to do.

Your **Red** and **Green** sections appear to be fixed width, meaning you can `SubString` each column to get the data.

The trick is writing the code to determine what you are reading and it usually requires you to know what section you were previously parsing. Your's appears to be as simple as checking to see if the line (possibly require a trim) parses to a date to know you are at the beginning of the process. From there Read until you get to the line that `StartsWith` `REF` to know that your following lines will be records until white-space appears for a few characters -- that's when you know are at your summary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions to read this file. Read each line one after the other. On each line you decide if this line starts a new entry, contains data from the red field or from the green field. You can do this by matching each of these lines to a regular expression, preferrably using groups to extract the actual data from them.

[MSDN about regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Somehow I don't think the OP knows _what is_ nor _is ready for_ "regular expressions"

Comment: @MickyD I do certainly agree, that OP might be inexperienced, but I think that attempting to do this without regex isn't a valuable learning experience, since it's just ugly messing around with strings.

Comment: @MickyD I actually know what regex is and have used.  But just to satisfy your negativity or sarcasm with me and/or my question I'm not very good at it.

Comment: @AlexanderHoischen If the OP doesn't understand why StreamReader doesn't have a a ReadGraph() method, I doubt he'll understand regexes (contrary to his usage claim).  Using regex by you and I though I completely agree.